# Install python package on Synology DiskStation

Tags: pip, installation, lxml, python-3.5, synology

**tldr:** Cannot install python-docx and lxml on my Synology DiskStation via pip3 or python 3 -m pip install.

**Long version:**
I already had some problem installing pip3 and django, but I got it working. Now I wanted to create doc files within django. So, python-docx was recommended. However I cannot just say "pip3 install python-docx".

[Here I have erased the old output, because it was not valid anymore.]

I do not know what to do next. I also tried to install libxml2:

```
python3 -m pip install libxml2
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libxml2
```

I googled, but many sites just recommend how to install certain dev packages on debian, which is not helping me.

Can you please tell me how to proceed?

**Edit**
After reading for hours and trying different things, including an install of entware, I have now a slightly different output.

```
python3 -m pip install python-docx
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing /volume1/homes/admin/.cache/pip/wheels/5c/b3/f7/0b2150abcd02387566859213e86c490e38070d0aad388c1105/python_docx-0.8.10-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lxml>=2.3.2
  Using cached lxml-4.5.0.tar.gz (4.5 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9_1bbtke/lxml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9_1bbtke/lxml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-h4ugg_2s
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9_1bbtke/lxml/
  Complete output (91 lines):
  Building lxml version 4.5.0.
  Building without Cython.
  ERROR: b'/bin/sh: xslt-config: command not found\n'
  ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

  Using build configuration of libxslt
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src
  creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src/lxml
  /opt/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DSYNO_FIX_FLAG_BUG -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=marvell-pj4 -mtune=marvell-pj4 -DSYNOPLAT_F_ARMV7 -O2 -fno-diagnostics-show-caret -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -include /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h -DSYNO_ENVIRONMENT -DBUILD_ARCH=32 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=600 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -Wno-unused-result -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src/lxml/etree.o -w
  gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
  cc1: fatal error: /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  Compile failed: command '/opt/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
  creating tmp
  cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInit_wqm9l9k.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInit_wqm9l9k.o
  unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory
  *********************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  *********************************************************************************
  error: command '/opt/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, python-docx
    Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9_1bbtke/lxml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9_1bbtke/lxml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_uhfue_j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /var/services/homes/admin/.local/include/python3.5m/lxml
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9_1bbtke/lxml/
    Complete output (90 lines):
    Building lxml version 4.5.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b'/bin/sh: xslt-config: command not found\n'
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

    Using build configuration of libxslt
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/html
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src
    creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src/lxml
    /opt/bin/gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DSYNO_FIX_FLAG_BUG -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL3 -DOPENSSL_NO_SSL2 -mhard-float -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=marvell-pj4 -mtune=marvell-pj4 -DSYNOPLAT_F_ARMV7 -O2 -fno-diagnostics-show-caret -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -include /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h -DSYNO_ENVIRONMENT -DBUILD_ARCH=32 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -DSDK_VER_MIN_REQUIRED=600 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -Wno-unused-result -fPIC -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/include/python3.5m -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.5/src/lxml/etree.o -w
    gcc: error trying to exec 'as': execvp: No such file or directory
    cc1: fatal error: /usr/syno/include/platformconfig.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    Compile failed: command '/opt/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInit31sc0ump.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInit31sc0ump.o
    unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory
    *********************************************************************************
    Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
    *********************************************************************************
    error: command '/opt/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9_1bbtke/lxml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9_1bbtke/lxml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-_uhfue_j/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /var/services/homes/admin/.local/include/python3.5m/lxml Check the logs for full command output.
```

If I see this correct, there is something wrong about something called "CC". But I still do not know what to do.

Comment: [`libxml2`](http://xmlsoft.org/) and [`libxslt`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) are not Python packages, you cannot install them with `pip`. They're libraries written in C and `lxml` is a Python wrapper for them. Install them (including development packages) with your system package manager. Or compile yourself from sources.

Comment: Thanks, this is already a start. I have now installed entware according to https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-Synology-NAS because I would not know how to install libxml2 otherwise. With this I installed libxml and python3-lxml. This seemed work fine.
But sadly the pip install still does not work.
The output is still the same as above.

Comment: I guess this is the important part:
"unable to execute '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc': No such file or directory
  Compile failed: command '/usr/local/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc' failed with exit status 1"
But I do not know what to do with that. :(

Comment: You need a compiler (and perhaps other developer tools — linker, `make`, etc.) `gcc` is the compiler.

Comment: Yes, I installed gcc via opkg. Still there is a problem (see updated output above).

Comment: "*xslt-config: command not found*" You didn't install headers (include files) and development packages for `libxml2` and `libxslt` (something like `-dev` or `-devel`).

Comment: I tried:
/opt/bin/opkg install libxml2-dev libxml2-devel libxslt-dev libxslt-devel
Unknown package 'libxml2-dev'.
Unknown package 'libxml2-devel'.
Unknown package 'libxslt-dev'.
Unknown package 'libxslt-devel'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package libxml2-dev.
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package libxml2-devel.
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package libxslt-dev.
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package libxslt-devel.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution. But I still have to test it. In the meantime you do not have to answer.

Via opkg I could install some of the packages and I also got a new install of python3. Somewhat confusing for me. So now I have a 2.7 that I never wanted from Synology and a 3.5 from the Synology package center and obviously a newer one from opkg.

However, I could install some packages, but others not. For example, I tried to install reportlab as a way to produce PDFs if python-docx would not run. But I could not install reportlab either, because it seems to miss something like libjpeg-dev or so. And I could also not find this in the opkg repo. However, suddenly python-docx could be installed and I am working with that now.

I am sorry that I cannot provide a better description for others who might have the same problem, but at least I tried to make my steps comprehensible.

Best regards